# jQuery works once when load on demand

Tags: jquery

I'm struggling with this issue here:
I'm using .load to load sections different sections of the website, to get jquery work on loaded content I tried loading js file together with content and it works great, but the problem is when user clicks on that section and it gets loaded again, jquery wont work anymore,
here is the js file I'm trying to make work every time user goes to that section:

```
$(".slider").each(function() {
    var radios = $(this).find(":checkbox").show();
    $("<div></div>").slider({
      min: parseInt(radios.first().val(), 10),
      max: parseInt(radios.last().val(), 10),
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        radios.filter("[value=" + ui.value + "]").click();
      }

    }).appendTo(this);

});
```

I think adding some sort of live function would be the solution,
any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: @BramVanroy What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do instead of loading jQuery file with your HTML. You can you use the [complete  callback](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function to add everything you need. This function is ran when your html is loaded to your selector.

```
$('#your-div').load(url, funciton(){
  $(".slider").each(function() {
    var radios = $(this).find(":checkbox").show();
    $("<div></div>").slider({
      min: parseInt(radios.first().val(), 10),
      max: parseInt(radios.last().val(), 10),
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        radios.filter("[value=" + ui.value + "]").click();
      }

    }).appendTo(this);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, some times I do stupid stuff when I make myself too busy with codes!